# Prevent any click event on the computer until macro has finished

Tags: ms-access, vba, mouseclick-event

Is the a way to prevent any mouse click on the computer until the end of a macro on Access VBA? The macro need a specific app to be in focus so I don't want to user to go elsewhere while the macro is running.

Comment: This could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What's the other app?

Comment: Might be so. He told us the problem (unallowed user-interactio) and he told us the way he wants to solve it (disable mouse). So technically it's not wrong, but he seems to lack self-searching.

Comment: I was thinking if the other app is something like Excel then just reference it - no need to have it in focus and the user can happily browse the internet, or open another app without affecting what Access is doing.

Comment: Therefore we have not enough information, but I get your point. You are right. But due to the lack of information it is in a grey zone as you can only assume it, but not proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WinApi [`BlockInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx) function to block any input, including task switching, or anything else.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function BlockInput Lib "User32.dll" (ByVal fBlockIt As Boolean) As Boolean

Private Sub DoStuff()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    BlockInput True
    'Do stuff here
    BlockInput False
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    BlockInput False 'Important! During message boxes, error handling, etc. input will still be blocked
    'Handle error here
Exit Sub
```

Note that `BlockInput` is kind of absolute. You can't do any stuff at all, except <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> to get out of it.

In some security configurations, `BlockInput` can be disabled, but generally, it's available without needing administrator rights or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

That can't be done. You can always go to another window or the taskbar.

Comment: Not true. See my answer.

Comment: Uh! I wouldn't even check this out. I trust you.

Answer (score 0):

Yo,

I cannot be done in VBA, but there are programs than shall be able to do that.
So you might have to find a workaround with the VBA-ProgramYouChoose-combination.

Here's the link:

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-restrict-or-disable-keyboard-mouse-and-even-power-button/

Those are the programms they discuss:

> KeyFreeze
>   ToddlerTrap
>   Toddler Keys
>   Kid-Key-Lock
>   KeyboardLock
>   Child Lock
>   Predator
>   Lock Windows

You will have to test those, as you only want your mouse to be disabled I would choose the Kid-Key-Lock.